# iText - inserting overlay text on top of all elements

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, overlay, itext

Using the [iText PDF library](http://www.lowagie.com/iText/), is it possible to freely (like "position: absolute" in CSS) insert overlay text or other elements on page, so that it gets rendered on top of all existing elements?

Thanks for all the help and tips in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Check out PDFStamper. It might be exactly what you're looking for.

Here's the tutorial.
http://itextdocs.lowagie.com/tutorial/general/copystamp/#pdfstamper

Answer (score 4):

Yes, *absolutely*.  Everything has to be absolutely positioned in PDF, so doing text flow, alignment, and so forth takes more work.  iText does all that for you if you ask, but it's still more work.

As Suvesh pointed out, `PdfStamper` works great for making changes to an existing PDF.  It's quite simple to add absolutely positioned text.

It's also possible to position text absolutely in a PDF you're building from scratch in iText.

In either case, you need to get a `PdfContentByte`.  In `PdfStamper`, you call `getOverContent(pageNum)` or `getUnderContent(pageNum)`.  With a PdfWriter, you just call `getOverContent()` or `getUnderContent()`.

With PdfWriter, you only need to get the over or under PdfContentByte once.  Every time it starts a new page, it'll suck all the content out and reset the object, ready for the next page.

OTOH, it doesn't start building pages until you call `doc.close()`, so you need to use a `PdfPageEvent` (I recommend deriving from `PdfPageEventHelper`) to write on the pages as they're generated... not a problem you'll have with a PdfStamper.